# How to find if a string starts with a number and a bracket in SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have some strings like

```
2) Some text
34) Some text more
5 Some other text
```

and I need to find if certain text starts with pattern some numbers (not fixed) followed by a closing bracket ')'

I tried:

```
If (PATINDEX('[^a-zA-Z]%', @myString) > 0)
begin
    print @myString
end
```

but it showed all the strings in the print, not the first two. How to resole this issue. Thanks!

Comment: what is the value of @myString variable , is the one column vale

Comment: How many numbers can prefix the `(`?

Comment: I am just looping through above texts, so `@myString = '2) Some text'` at first, then `34) Some text more` and so on. I am checking all of them.

Comment: @DavidG: Numbers are not fixed atm. It's between 1 - 500

Comment: And it will always be below 500?

Comment: @DavidG: yes, it is below 500 always.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't have great pattern matching but if you know that the numbers prefixing the `)` will always be less then 500, you can do this:

```
DECLARE @myString VARCHAR(100) = '266) Some text'

If (PATINDEX('[0-9])%', @myString) > 0) OR         --Check for one digit
   (PATINDEX('[0-9][0-9])%', @myString) > 0) OR    --Check for two digits
   (PATINDEX('[0-9][0-9][0-9])%', @myString) > 0) --Check for three digits
begin
    print @myString
end
```

Comment: I think `NOT` is not needed here, as it excludes the required result

Comment: I was just matching your code posted above, have removed it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This is working fine for my requirement +1

Comment: And a better check for the last entry can be: `'[0-4][0-9][0-9])%'` ;).

Comment: @shA.t Well that depends on OP, leaving it as it is now allows the number to go up to 999, but adding the `0-4` restriction is valid.

Answer (score 5):

This will not consider all combinations but you can check. For example it certainly will fail if there will be several ')' symbols in string :

```
select * from t
where s like '[0-9]%)%' and s not like '[0-9]%[^0-9]%)%'
```

Fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3b5fd/3

Comment: Thanks. This is a nice solution +1

Comment: The problem of this solution is for a data like `'3) 4) Some text more'` in `s` ;).

Comment: @shA.t . . . I don't see that being a problem.  The code would correctly identify that the string starts with a number followed by a paren.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Surely this code will fail when a second paren is present?

Answer (score 2):

This will provide the results you need.  You basically do a combination of

1. Check to see if the string contains a parenthesis
2. Check and see if any characters before the parenthesis are not numeric

   ```
   SELECT
       mystring,
       CHARINDEX(')',mystring) as containsParenthesis,
       SUBSTRING(mystring,0,CHARINDEX(')',mystring)) as beforeParenthesis,
       PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',SUBSTRING(mystring,0,CHARINDEX(')',mystring))) as containsSomethingBesidesNumbers
   FROM
       (
       SELECT '2) Some text' as mystring UNION ALL
       SELECT '34) Some text more' UNION ALL
       SELECT '5 Some other text'
       )t
   WHERE
       CHARINDEX(')',mystring) > 0 AND PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',SUBSTRING(mystring,0,CHARINDEX(')',mystring))) = 0
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
SET @MYSTRING = REPLACE(@MYSTRING, '.', '');
If ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(@mystring, 1, charindex(')', @mystring) - 1)) = 1 
begin
      print @mystring
end
```

Comment: Close, but `isnumeric()` accepts values like "123.4" and "5e6".

Comment: I think you've made it worse!

Comment: It now matches strings like `1.2.3.4.5`

Answer (score 1):

```
SET @MYSTRING = REPLACE(@MYSTRING, '.', '');
If ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(@mystring, 1, charindex(')', @mystring) - 1)) = 1 
begin
      print @mystring
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `ISNUMERIC`

```
SET @mystringtrimmed = SUBSTRING(@mystring, 1, CHARINDEX(')', @mystring) - 1);

IF ISNUMERIC(@mystringtrimmed) = 1 
BEGIN
        PRINT @mystring
END
```